# Correct way to insert/update Codable struct document/array to Firestore

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

My Firestore document structure, i created it via Android:

```
--- Document
----- testA (object)
----- testB (array)
------- 0: Device item 1
------- 1: Device item 2
```

I have following struct:

```
import Foundation
public struct Device: Codable {
    var manufacturer: String?
    var model: String?
    var osVersion: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case manufacturer
        case model
        case osVersion
    }
}
```

My device object

```
let currentDevice = Device(manufacturer: "a", model: "b", osVersion: "c")
```

Test A: Update `Device` to Document.
I tried below code:

```
db.collection("testCollection").document("testDoc").updateData([testA: currentDevice])
...
```

Test B: Add `Device` to `testB` array.

```
db.collection("testCollection").document("testDoc")
.updateData([testA: FieldValue.arrayUnion([currentDevice])])
```

It all cause below error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported type: __SwiftValue'`

I also checked official document but it does not show anyway to update struct object to Firestore. What can i do? Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? If I update the whole document, it works as expected. Only when using `updateData` I run into this error, which makes me think that itsnot a serialising issue.

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully this helps somebody out.

First, in the original example above, `testA` is not quoted.  The field key is a string.  It should be "testA"

In order to save an item to an array on a document ref, using `updateData`, swift structs/classes need to be encoded into a dictionary.  *FirebaseFirestoreSwift* helps with this by providing a specialized *encoder*.  Otherwise, you can manually convert from your struct into the expected `[String: Any]` dictionary.

This example uses *FirebaseFirestoreSwift*

```swift
        let currentDevice = Device(
             manufacturer: "a", 
             model: "b", 
             osVersion: "c"
        )
        // declare outside of the try/catch block
        let encoded: [String: Any]
        do {
            // encode the swift struct instance into a dictionary
            // using the Firestore encoder
            encoded = try Firestore.Encoder().encode(currentDevice)
        } catch {
            // encoding error
            handleError(error)
            return
        }

        let fieldKey = "testA"

        // add a new item to the "testA" array.
        db.collection("testCollection").document("testDoc")
            .updateData(
                [
                    fieldKey: FieldValue.arrayUnion([encoded])
                ]
            ) { error in
                guard let error = error else {
                    // no error, that's great
                    return
                }

                // uh oh, firestore error
                handleError(error)
                return

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this error is related to the fact that Firestore is not able to serialise different types of variables and arrays at the same time - in your case the problem seems related to the `currentDevice` variable, that Firestore is not being able to identify.

It seems that you will need to modify the below part, for your application to be able to insert the data.

```
...  
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case manufacturer
            case model
            case osVersion
        }
...
```

Since you are not using one "variable" to add the information for the `manufacturer`, `model` and `osVersion`. I would recommend you to check this question from the Community [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51951473/how-to-set-data-to-a-array-with-objects-in-firestore), to get a possible solution - adapting to your case - of how to convert your data for Firestore to be able to understand.

Let me know if the information helped you!